# which PHP data type accepts numbers and dash

Tags: types, phpmyadmin

Which Phpmyadmin data type accepts Dash(-) and numbers all together. I have to store like the data as in 50-50-50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are including dashes (-), mysql will not take the characters as an INT.

Your best bet would be to use TINYTEXT or the more arcurate VARCHAR.

If you know your character format is always going to be 00-00-00, then you can use VARCHAR(8) which means the database will expect up to 8 characters but no more, saving in space on the database.

If the format is actually for dates, then you should be using the DATE format.

You can find out more in the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-overview.html).

Comment: thanx mate for the answer. I just realized that i got the answer. by the way thanx again!! Cheers!!